# ER_ACCESS_DENIED_NO_PASSWORD_ERROR meaning confusion

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I wrote a js script and it works fine locally, however, when I deploy it to my ubuntu-server I can not connect to the mysql-database. I am getting following error-message:

```
Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
    at PromisePool.query (/root/platformbackend/node_modules/mysql2/promise.js:330:22)
    at IdentificationRepositoryImpl.<anonymous> (/root/platformbackend/src/Repository/IdentificationRepositoryImpl.ts:19:14)
    at step (/root/platformbackend/src/Repository/IdentificationRepositoryImpl.ts:46:23)
    at Object.next (/root/platformbackend/src/Repository/IdentificationRepositoryImpl.ts:27:53)
    at /root/platformbackend/src/Repository/IdentificationRepositoryImpl.ts:21:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/root/platformbackend/src/Repository/IdentificationRepositoryImpl.ts:17:12)
    at IdentificationRepositoryImpl.setupTable (/root/platformbackend/src/Repository/IdentificationRepositoryImpl.ts:61:16)
    at /root/platformbackend/src/SitServer/SitServer.ts:60:24
    at Array.map (<anonymous>) {
  code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_NO_PASSWORD_ERROR',
  errno: 1698,
  sqlState: '28000',
  sqlMessage: "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'"
```

The code, the error originates from is (in condensed form) following:

```
const connectionOptions = {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST || 'localhost',
    user: process.env.DB_USER || 'root',
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD || '',
    database: process.env.DB_NAME || 'test_db',
};

const connection = createPool(connectionOptions);

const insertId = await connection
    .promise()
    .query(sql)
    .then(result => result)
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

Now I am confused, what the error code `ER_ACCESS_DENIED_NO_PASSWORD_ERROR` actually means.

- Does it mean, that I provided an empty password?
- Or does it mean, that it didn't receive a password and it thinks there is no password provided (not even an empty one)?
- Or does it mean, that it doesn't expect a password to be provided, but it got one?

I have tried...

- ...setting the root's password to an empty string and providing an empty string as password
- ...setting the root's password to an empty string and providing no password entry in `connectionOptions`
- ...setting the root's password and providing the password in the password entry in `connectionOptions`

but all with the same error as outcome.

Some research and approaches I also already tried:

- [MariaDB connection to ExpressJS access denied no password error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59332683/mariadb-connection-to-expressjs-access-denied-no-password-error)
- [Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (Mysql::Error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081339/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes-mysqlerror)
- [ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' at Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029177/error-1698-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-at-ubuntu-18-04)
- [ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: #591](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/591)
- [MySQL :: MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual :: B.3.1 Server Error Message Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-error-reference.html)

Thank you for any help, pointing me in the right direction. If I'm missing any debugging-details, I'm happy to provide them upon request.

---

Sidenote: I know I shouldn't use the root-user, it's a testing server.

Comment: Did you set a password on the MySQL root account

Comment: I did, yes... and then I removed it for testing reasons and added it again :/

Comment: Then possibly `password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD || 'Put_The_password_in_Here',`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this error means that you tried to login without a password. And yes, I think MySQL considers a password of `''` (empty string) the same as no password.

Check that `process.env.DB_PASSWORD` is set. Maybe log to the console whether it was set:

```js
console.info('process.env.DB_PASSWORD was ' + (!process.env.DB_PASSWORD ? 'NOT ' : '') + 'set')
```

I think whether or not logging in without a password is allowed is a MySQL setting that you can edit somewhere in the .ini file, but in order to prevent the hassle I just always use the password `secret` for my testing instances and have code like this:

```js
const connectionOptions = {
    // ...
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD || 'secret',
    // ...
};
```

Comment: yes, it is set... i'll do the `password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD || 'secret'` anyways, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Oh great, having followed [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-18-04) the fourth time, it suddenly worked... I'm sorry for any inconvenience.

If I find out, what went different this time, I'll update this very unsatisfying answer.

Comment: Been there.  https://unijokes.com/joke-2082/